# Azure storage not showing up on server?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an azure storage account and two web roles.  The storage account is used for the web roles.

The other day I put a file in the storage account but the server couldn't see it.  After lots of refresh attempts the server saw the file, only to go away again on the next refresh.

To fix that problem I re-deployed my config file from my computer.  After that the files started showing up.

I just put a javascript file in my /js/ folder on my storage account.  Normally, this file would show up right away.  It's been about 10 minutes and I still can't see the file.

Is this expected behavior?  I thought that once a file is deployed it is immediately available to all servers connected to that storage account.  Anyone know how to fix this?

p.s.  I'm using cloud berry to deploy

Answer (score 1):

Run Fiddler (http://fiddler2.com). Sometimes the issue can be seen there. It's correct that once a blob has been successfully uploaded, all subsequent requests should see it. (There should be no lag.)

That leads me to guess that either the upload failed (and CloudBerry didn't notice/indicate that) or the code that's looking for the blob is failing. Certainly either is possible, but Fiddler makes it easier to spot this sort of thing, since you should see the HTTP traffic going back and forth and spot the error.

Comment: Thanks man, I enjoy your blog.  It's just a javascript file so if I go to www.mysite.com/js/mynewscriptfile.js I get a 404 not found.

I can actually pull the file back down from the blob storage through cloudberry so I think it's a problem with my web role.  If I RDP into the server I can't see the file at C:\Resources\directory\31a74bbe0fea42bdacb964a9ba73eeda.WebRole.Sites\trainerroad.com\scripts

I'm also using umbraco and the umbraco accelerator for azure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I just deployed a staging instance of the same web role linked to the same storage account.  This one has the new files and I added a file and it showed up on the server.  The production web roles still don't see the new file.  Is this a bug that I should log with microsoft?

Comment: @Nate --> It looks like you're uploading the file in Azure Blob Storage but for some reason you're expecting this file to show up in your role. This would not work. Once the file is uploaded in Azure storage, you would need to get the URL of that blob (e.g. myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/js/mynewscriptfile.js) and use it in your ASP.Net code.

Comment: @Gaurav But it does work...most of the time :).  It might be some setup that the umbraco accelerator does, not sure.  I bet smarx would know because he helped build it.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like the behavior you're expecting is very specific to the Umbraco solution accelerator. (It does syncing among role instances through a blob storage container.) I guess I'd verify that the file is in the right container and that you're looking in the right place on the role instance. If you want to send me email (Steve.Marx@microsoft.com) and share credentials, I'd be happy to take a look for you.